# How to align this text in the center of its parent flex item?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have some react-native code, where I have a pop-up modal. I created it using flex, but for some reason the text will not vertically align. I solved it using top = 30%, but then my touchable opacities(surrounding the texts) do not span all of the free space available. And I feel this is a hacky solution.

Curious if there is a better one, to automatically align the text vertically and make sure the touchable opacities take up the free space available to them?

Below is my code:

```
<Modal
    isVisible={confirmationVisible}
    onBackdropPress={() => toggleConfirmation()}
    style={styles.confirmationModal}
>
    <Text style={styles.confirmationTitle}>Would you like to add a beacon to {assetName}?</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.confirmationContainer} onPress={() => navigateAway("AddAssetScreenFinish")}>
        <Text style={styles.confirmationText}>No, I'm done</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.confirmationContainer} onPress={() => navigateAway("AddBeaconExistingScreen")}>
        <Text style={styles.confirmationText}>Yes, an existing Beacon</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.confirmationContainer} onPress={() => navigateAway("AddBeaconScreen")}>
        <Text style={styles.confirmationText}>Yes, a new Beacon</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

</Modal>
```

Below is my styling:

```
confirmationModal: {
    flex: 0.3,
    width: "60%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginTop: "auto",
    marginBottom: "auto",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    borderRadius: 8
},
confirmationTitle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 5,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
},
confirmationContainer: {
    borderTopColor: "lightgrey",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    width: "100%"
},
confirmationText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: COLORS.purple
},
```

[image: Modal Image]

---

Edit:
using this [modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal) if curious
Also, have tried justifyContent on confirmationContainer but it does not work, unsure why

---

Edit2:
Got the solution. Seems flex is scaling the height and width had to be set manually for my text element. Removing the justifyContent and alignItems from a parent container, I was able to use textAlignVertical for my title and scale titleContainer vs touchableContainers with flex 2 and flex 1 respectively. Not sure what is going on, but the touchable now scales the whole free space and the text is aligned vertically...used AnthonyDev220's solution and reworked it so marked him as best answer, updated styles jsx did not change:

```
confirmationModal: {
    flex: 0.3,
    width: "60%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginTop: "auto",
    marginBottom: "auto",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    borderRadius: 8
},
confirmationTitle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    flex: 2,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
},
confirmationContainer: {
    borderTopColor: "lightgrey",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%"
},
confirmationText: {
    marginTop: "auto",
    marginBottom: "auto",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: COLORS.purple
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `textAlignVertical: "center"` to your `confirmationText`

or

Try wrapping your  component inside a  component and then style your  componenet.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.confirmationContainer} onPress={() => navigateAway("AddAssetScreenFinish")}>
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center"}}>
        <Text style={styles.confirmationText}>No, I'm done</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

same for your other two `<Text>` components.

Comment: Should have mentioned, but I did try this. Does not work for some reason

Comment: I see. Then, I think you could try wrapping your ```<Text>``` component inside a ```<View>``` component and then style your ```<View>``` componenet. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Tried the updated answers...whenever I make flex == 1 for the new view it does not display the text at all...when I remove it nothing changes.

Comment: Very strange. Have you tried the the first solution, which is to set ```textAlignVertical``` to ```center```.

Comment: I did. I actually just solved it but do not understand what is going on at all. Regardless, it works and should scale well. I used your solutions so will mark your solution as correct. Updating my edit to show what worked

Comment: styling is always very confusing in terms of precedence. Meanwhile, these components have their own style props to pass from a higher component conflicting with your custom styling. Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
confirmationContainer: {
    display: flex,
    justifyContent: center,
    alignItems:center,
    borderTopColor: "lightgrey",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    width: "100%"
}
```